# TF Keras Text Processing - Classification Model

Tags: keras, tensorflow, predictive-modeling, text-classification

I'm trying to put together a script that classifies comments into either adequate or inadequate.  I put a question up here earlier with all my code, but I think I've isolated the problem down into the setup of the model, so I deleted that one, and hopefully this is more streamlined and easy to follow.  The example i'm trying to follow is the classic IMDB comment, where the comments are either positive or negative, but again in my instance, adequate or not.  My tokenizer and text cleanup and padding are working well, so i have my training dataset that returns my tokenized sequences properly.  I think where i'm going wrong is as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 300),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max')

callbacks = [es]
history = model.fit(train_seqs, train_df['adq'].values,
                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    verbose = 2,
                    validation_split = 0.2,
                    callbacks = callbacks)

model.evaluate(test_seqs, test_df['adq'].values)
```

My main problem with the output, is that when i run the model to predict comments with no classification, the model is returning the same output value for every single comment.  I've done some research, and people have suggested normalizing the batch, and i tried adding a layer for batch normalization in my model, but that doesn't seem to help either.  Can someone please have a look and show me where I'm going wrong?  Thanks very much for your help!

Here's my entire script per my comment below:

````
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import string
import re


NUM_WORDS = 10000
SEQ_LEN = 512
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 300
BATCH_SIZE = 70
EPOCHS = 20
HIGHEST_PROTOCOL = 3
THRESHOLD = 0.60


train_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documents\IMDBtrain.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documents\IMDBtest.csv')

def clean_text(text, remove_stopwords=True):
    '''Clean the text, with the option to remove stopwords'''

    # Convert words to lower case and split them
    text = text.lower().split()

    # Optionally, remove stop words
    if remove_stopwords:
        stops = ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 'your', 'yours',
                 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 'she', 'her', 'hers', 'herself',
                 'its', 'its', 'itself', 'they', 'them', 'their', 'theirs', 'themslves', 'what', 'which',
                 'who', 'whom', 'this', 'that', 'these', 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'be',
                 'been', 'be', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 'do', 'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a',
                 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'because', 'as', 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at',
                 'by', 'for', 'with', 'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 'through', 'during', 'before',
                 'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 'out', 'on', 'off', 'over',
                 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why',
                 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'most', 'more', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no',
                 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 'will',
                 'just', 'don', 'should', 'now']
        text = [w for w in text if not w in stops]

    text = " ".join(text)

    # Clean the text
    text = re.sub(r"<br />", " ", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[^a-z]", " ", text)
    text = re.sub(r"   ", " ", text) # Remove any extra spaces
    text = re.sub(r"  ", " ", text)

    # Return a list of words
    return(text)

train_df["text"] = train_df["text"].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
test_df["text"] = test_df["text"].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
train_df = train_df.sample(frac = 1).reset_index(drop = True)
test_df = test_df.sample(frac = 1).reset_index(drop = True)


tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words = NUM_WORDS, oov_token = '<UNK>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_df['text'])

train_seqs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df['text'])
test_seqs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_df['text'])

train_seqs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_seqs, maxlen = SEQ_LEN, padding = 'post')
test_seqs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_seqs, maxlen = SEQ_LEN, padding = 'post')


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(NUM_WORDS, EMBEDDING_SIZE),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max')

callbacks = [es]
history = model.fit(train_seqs, train_df['adq'].values,
                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    validation_split = 0.2,
                    callbacks = callbacks)

model.evaluate(test_seqs, test_df['adq'].values)


model.save('model.ps1')
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

del model
del tokenizer


loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.ps1')

with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

def prepare_predict_data(tokenizer, comments):
    seqs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(comments)
    seqs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(seqs, maxlen = SEQ_LEN, padding = 'post')
    return seqs


comments_to_pred = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documents\IMDBload.csv')
my_comments = comments_to_pred.to_numpy().tolist()


my_seqs = prepare_predict_data(loaded_tokenizer, my_comments)
preds = loaded_model.predict(my_seqs)
pred_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['text', 'adq'])
pred_df['text'] = my_comments
pred_df['adq'] = preds
print(pred_df.head(20))
pred_df['adq'] = pred_df['adq'].apply(lambda x: 'pos' if x > THRESHOLD else 'neg')
#print(pred_df.head(40))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are average pooling your embedding layer. Make sure that it is done over the words rather than over the embedding axis. If your embedding output is (Batch, Words, 300), you want to apply GlobalAveragePool1D to axis 1 (words).

One issue here could be though that by averaging over the words, you are messing things up by padding your input. If you pad a 10 word input to 25, and then take an average over all 25, where 15/25 are all zero, you will bias your averaging in an almost random way (random to the length of the input) which your non-recurrent model cannot understand. You would want to add an additional lambda layer to only average over the length of the input, and pass the length of the input as an additional input.

Comment: thanks very much for the help!  i removed the GlobalAveragePooling line and reran the script.  I know it's a bit sparse with only the embedding and sigmoid layer, but i just need to get it working first.  And that note, i'm only looking to classify my comment as adequate or inadequate, so that's why i went with sigmoid/sequential, as opposed to LSTM or softmax, etc.  I'll have a look at the others.  Rerunning the script, i now get an error on the values/shape (AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape), going to try and work this out.

Comment: Just updating here, removing the GlobalAveragePool1D from my model has actually created some problems, most notably the prediction output is now a different shape. More importantly, my original problem still remains, where all my prediction outputs for each comment, are still coming back with exactly the same value.  I'm going to do some more reading to see if I can't track this down, but if you have more thoughts, or if anyone else has any ideas, please help, thanks very much!

Comment: I see. You want to average the embeddings for each word. If your embedding output is (Batch, Words, 300), you want to apply GlobalAveragePool1D to axis 1 (words). Then your Global1D output shape will be (batch, 300), and you can do a sigmoid classification on that.

Comment: One issue here could be though that by averaging over the words, you are messing things up by padding your input. If you pad a 10 word input to 25, and then take an average over all 25, where 15/25 are all zero, you will bias your averaging in an almost random way (random to the length of the input) which your non-recurrent model cannot understand. You would want to add an additional lambda layer to only average over the length of the input, and pass the length of the input as an additional input.

Comment: I just tried cutting the batch size down to about 70 to minimize the effects of the padding, but the same problem is coming up.  I've edited my original post to include my entire script, would you have a quick look?  I do GREATLY appreciate the help, i'm not just on here asking questions, I'm scouring the documentation to see if i can see what i'm doing wrong as well.  I have a feeling that my inputs to the embedding and dense layers are also causing issues.  Also, i tried adding to your rep, but I'm still new here, so it's recorded my up vote haha.

Comment: The lambda functions i currently have just iterate through my comments to clean up the text as part of my function clean_text.  FYI i have the stopwords in there, my environment is giving me issues when i try to import the NLTK stopword list, so I had to do that in a list as you see.

Comment: Do you mean batch size or sequence length? You want SEQ_LEN to be shorter. Select it based on a histogram of your sequence lengths. Your code looks fine to me so I think it is either a hyper parameter selection or a data issue. It seems to me that you are taking an average of a variable amount of zeros, which is injecting a lot of noise to your  output. You can solve this with a lambda layer. Other issues may be: you use the base learning rate for Adam, your output may  not be formatted correctly (should not be one-hot encoded - should  be 0/1 array of shape (num_samples,))

Comment: The lambda layer (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) should use tf.slice like so: slice_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: slice_and_average(x)) where slice_and_average takes in the embedded layer and an input_length which is the true, unpadded length of each sequence in the batch. It would then use tf.slice to extract the non-padded items, and tf.math.reduce_mean to average them.